# u2020+Mortar DrawerLayout and actionbar issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout, dagger, mortar

I'm playing around with [u2020-mortar](https://github.com/lemonlabs/u2020-mortar)mode of Jake Wharton's [u2020](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020)sample app that contains NavigationDrawer. What I'm trying to do is make NavidationDrawer to move content wit actionbar as it opens. I'm doing it like this:

```
coreView = (CoreView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.core, null); //extends DrawerLayout

ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
ViewGroup decorChild = (ViewGroup) decor.getChildAt(0);

decor.removeView(decorChild);
decor.addView(coreView);

coreView.getContentFrame().addView(decorChild);
```

this technique I borrowed from [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)lib.

But as a result actionbar is absent and all the views are behind notification area like on screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]
So question is why it is like this, what am I doing wrong and how can I reach the goal ?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I did not get it. What do you mean by define ?

Comment: My mistake. I thought it was a typo... looks like an Unicode char!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein u2020 is Unicode char called dagger. Jake Wharton called his app u2020 as it is example of usage Dagger framework.

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't even know what Dagger is.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein it is lightweight dependency injection framework [link](http://square.github.io/dagger/)